# Material-UI: Prevent onClick from triggering for an element positioned under another in sticky Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my table I have a checkbox at the start of every row, including the table head, which has the sticky property.

When scrolling the table, rows will move behind the head row. If I go to click the head row's checkbox with another row's checkbox under it, they will both trigger their `onClick` functions.

[image: Layered checkboxes]

The jsx is equivalent to the following:

```
<Table>
   <TableHead style={{position: "sticky"}}>
      <TableRow>
         <TableCell>
            <Checkbox/>
         </TableCell>
         ...
      </TableRow>
   </TableHead>

   <TableBody>
      <TableRow>
         <TableCell>
            <Checkbox/>
         </TableCell>
         ...
      </TableRow>
      ...
   </TableBody>

</Table>
```

How can I prevent the checkbox underneath the head from being clicked when it is not visible?

Comment: can you please share whole code on some playground? it will be easier to find out :)

Comment: According to me it should not because they are not part of the same branch in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding your custom style to create a fixed header. You can simply set [`stickyHeader`](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header) props to `true`, which will also fix your problem:

```js
<Table stickyHeader>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67016497/prevent-onclick-triggering-for-an-element-positioned-under-another]